# How to get comments belongs to particular post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning rails by creating a blog. I have 3 models as category, comments and posts.

I want to get comments belongs to a particular post. How can I get that?

```
#model/post.rb

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :category

  def latestcomments
   // 
  end
end

#model/comment.rb

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :post
end


#model/category.rb
   has_many :posts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
post = Post.find(:id).includes(:comments)
```

to get comments of that post

```
comments = post.comments
```

In comments table **post_id** column refers relationship bet. posts and comments table

Comment: I want to define a method in model. 

``def latestcomments 
   comments = post.comments
return comments``

Am I doing it right?

Comment: just write def latestcomments self.comments end with in method.

Comment: Why you are create latestcomments method to fetch comements ? Are you putting any other conditions with in that method?

Comment: yes, I want to put some conditions on it later. I guess .last can provide the lastest comments from the table

Comment: that was dumb mistake, I was trying to access the :params on a model :D